# Pytorch Mapping One Hot Tensor to max of input tensor

Tags: numpy, pytorch, tensor

I have a code for mapping the following tensor to a one hot tensor:
`tensor([ 0.0917 -0.0006  0.1825 -0.2484]) --> tensor([0., 0., 1., 0.])`. Position 2 has the max value `0.1825` and this should map as 1 to position 2 in the One Hot vector.

The following code does the job.

```
a = torch.Tensor(np.array([ 0.0917, -0.0006,  0.1825, -0.2484]))
b = torch.zeros(4)
b[np.argmax(a)]=1
print(a, b)
```

Is there a better or straight forward 1 line of code for this? like....`torch.nn.functional.one_hot(torch.Tensor(a), num_classes=4)` (here I got `RuntimeError: one_hot is only applicable to index tensor.`)

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: `(a==a.max()).to('float64')`? Although, that gives different output when `a` has more than 1 max, e.g. `a=[1,2,3,3]`.

Comment: ```a.max()``` becomes ```tensor(0.1825)``` then casting to float64 gives the error ```RuntimeError: Invalid device string: 'float64'```

Comment: this worked ```(a==a.max()).long()```

Comment: yes, let's assume maximum is unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tensor class has an argmax method:

```
import torch

a = torch.Tensor(np.array([ 0.0917, -0.0006,  0.1825, -0.2484]))

one_hot = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(a.argmax(), num_classes=4)
```